# mode returns Exception: Must produce aggregated value

Tags: pandas

for this dataframe

```
   values  ii
0     3.0   4
1     0.0   1
2     3.0   8
3     2.0   5
4     2.0   1
5     3.0   5
6     2.0   4
7     1.0   8
8     0.0   5
9     1.0   1
```

This line returns "Must ptoduce aggregated values

```
bii2=df.groupby(['ii'])['values'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

While this line works

```
bii3=df.groupby('ii')['values'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0])
```

Could you explain why is that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Problem is `mode` return sometimes 2 or more values, check solution with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
bii2=df.groupby(['ii'])['values'].apply(pd.Series.mode)
print (bii2)
ii   
1   0    0.0
    1    1.0
    2    2.0
4   0    2.0
    1    3.0
5   0    0.0
    1    2.0
    2    3.0
8   0    1.0
    1    3.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

And pandas `agg` need scalar in output, so return error. So if select first value it working nice

```
bii3=df.groupby('ii')['values'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x).iat[0])
print (bii3)
ii
1    0.0
4    2.0
5    0.0
8    1.0
Name: values, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jezrael points out, `mode` sometimes returns more than one value. So you could try this:

```
bii3=df.groupby('ii')['values'].agg(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x).to_list())
```

With the `.to_list()` part what happens is that for every value of ii you'll get a list instead of just one value. You should get something like:

```
ii
1    [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
4         [2.0, 3.0]
5    [0.0, 2.0, 3.0]
8         [1.0, 3.0]
Name: mode, dtype: object
```